# List image url from json to a JavaScript slideshow fuction

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I need to list image URLs from JSON to a JavaScript slideshow function.

Can someone show me how I can replace the list of URLs from the function with the ones from JSON object?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").backgroundCycle({
      imageUrls: [
        'res/img/bg1.jpg',
        'res/img/bg2.jpg',
        'res/img/bg3.jpg'
      ],
      fadeSpeed: 2000,
      duration: 5000,
      backgroundSize: SCALING_MODE_COVER
    });
  });
</script>
```

Here is the JSON:

```
{
    "topbanners": [
        "http:\/\/kuuza.co.tz\/serengeti_090.jpg",
        "http:\/\/kuuza.co.tz\/p4030235.jpg",
        "http:\/\/kuuza.co.tz\/banner1.jpg"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function getUrls() {
            var obj = {
                "topbanners": [
                    "http:\/\/kuuza.co.tz\/serengeti_090.jpg",
                    "http:\/\/kuuza.co.tz\/p4030235.jpg",
                    "http:\/\/kuuza.co.tz\/banner1.jpg"
                ]
            };
            var banners = obj.topbanners;
            var urls = [];

            for (var i = 0; i < banners.length; i++) {
                urls.push(banners[i]);

            }
            return urls;
        }

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("body").backgroundCycle({
                imageUrls: getUrls(),
                fadeSpeed: 2000,
                duration: 5000,
                backgroundSize: SCALING_MODE_COVER
            });
        });
```